# Is it possible to drag and drop columns in sencha touch grid

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I would like to know, is it possible to drag and drop columns of Sencha touch grid. If yes, anybody can point me to any working example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example in Sencha. [Example](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid/)

It is Grid to Grid drag and drop, but you can customize it according to your need.